# decode base64 with dollar sign in ruby 1.8.5

Tags: ruby, base64, decode

I have base64-encoded string (with two dollar signs, so it's not a common base64 string)

The problem: Base64.decode64 (or .unpack("m")) decodes it just fine on my local machine(ruby 1.8.6), but with ruby 1.8.5 (the version used by Heroku) it doesn't work

Any ideas ?

**edit:**

I have :

$$YTo1OntzOjM6Im1pZCI7czo3OiI3MTE5Njg3IjtzOjQ6Im5hbWUiO3M6MjE6IkthbnllIFdlc3QgLSBTdHJvbmd
lciI7czo0OiJsaW5rIjtzOjQ4OiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmVhc3kxNS5jb20vMDIgU3Ryb25nZXIgKFNuaXBwZXQpMS5tcD
MiO3M6OToiX3BsYXl0aW1lIjtzOjU6IjgzMjAwIjtzOjg6Il9uZXh0aWRzIjtzOjEzNDoiMjc1ODE0MDYsMjc0MDE1
NzAsMjI1MTU0MDMsMTU1ODM2NjYsMTYzMTUzMzksMjgwNDY5MTUsMzAzOTMxODksMzUyMDAyMTMsMjIwNTE1MzAsMj
c1NTg1MTQsMTM3ODkyNTYsMTk4MTY5OTgsMzA0NzI4MDEsMTUyNTk5NzksMTg5OTkxMzciO30=

I successed in decoding it with '...'.unpack("m") locally but not on the heroku server (ruby 1.8.5, maybe the ruby version it's not the issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar sign is not part of the Base64 specification.

Simply strip the leading `$$` before unpacking:

```
str.sub(/^\$*/, '').unpack('m')
```

To strip all non-Base64 characters, emulating new (Ruby 1.8.6) behaviour,

> `str.gsub(/[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789\+\/]/, '').unpack('m')`

Ruby 1.8.6 will ignore all non-Base64 symbols (including the `$`) inside the string to decode, whereas 1.8.5 will stop processing at the first such character (see `pack.c` in the Ruby source.)

Comment: Wouldn't `str.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9+\/]/, '')` be more convenient?